# gInitialPages is not defined bootstrapped extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I am working on Firefox extension that overwrite new tab page and I need to hide my page URL from address bar. I use this code:

```
if (gInitialPages.indexOf(NEW_TAB_URL)===-1)  gInitialPages.push(NEW_TAB_URL);
```

It works correctly in XUL Overlay code, but I'm getting an error when I try to make my application restartless and move this code to bootstrap.js:

> gInitialPages is not defined

So, how can I use `gInitialPages` (or anything similar) in bootstrapped extensions?

Comment: Along with nmaiers solution below here's another boiler plate you can use: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/1c7ab2c49c7640ff84db just edit in the loadIntoWindow and unloadFromWindow.

Comment: It seems your current code version throws ReferenceError: Services is not defined (missing import?)

Comment: Import services with Cu.import('resources://gre/modules/Services.jsm')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrapped/restartless extensions do NOT automagically run in the context of (a) window(s).
`bootstrap.js` runs in an own context, only once per application instance, not in the browser window.

You'll need to:

- Manually enumerate all existing browser windows.
- Listen for new browser windows as they are opened.

And then manipulate the variable in those windows.

See [Mardak's example](https://github.com/Mardak/restartless/blob/examples/shiftAllBrowsers/bootstrap.js) on how you could do that, in particular `watchWindows` and `unload`.

Comment: Thanks for code example, it's work (with window.gInitialPages). Merely, I thought that gInitialPages must be somewhere in "global" context.